# Mountain Lion: Launchpad always scrolls left

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, launchpad

When activating the launchpad in Mountain Lion, and try to scroll to one of the panes to the right, after a second it automatically scrolls left again. This is on a mid 2011 MBP, with no other devices attached. Does anyone else have this problem, and how do I solve it?

Comment: I have this problem as well. It doesn't happen all the time, and I'm not sure what action triggers it to start. I assume it's a conflict with some other software I'm running, but don't know where to start.